# WordPress redirect function

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I am in the process of building a private WooCommerce portal for clients to order from.

I am trying to avoid bloated membership plugins, found this code online and works well however I would like it to redirect to url if 'any' page is visited by a logged out user not just a single page ID

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_if_user_not_logged_in' );

function redirect_if_user_not_logged_in() {

    if ( is_page('slug || ID') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) { //example can be is_page(23) where 23 is page ID

        wp_redirect( 'http://your-redirect-page-here '); 
 
     exit;// never forget this exit since its very important for the wp_redirect() to have the exit / die
   
   }
   
}
```

I have tried removing the page check and also is_page() as mentioned in the wordpress documentation

```
// When any single Page is being displayed.
is_page();
 
// When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.
is_page( 42 );
 
// When the Page with a post_title of "Contact" is being displayed.
is_page( 'Contact' );
 
// When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.
is_page( 'about-me' );
 
/*
 * Returns true when the Pages displayed is either post ID 42,
 * or post_name "about-me", or post_title "Contact".
 * Note: the array ability was added in version 2.5.
 */
is_page( array( 42, 'about-me', 'Contact' ) );
```

Comment: Have you considered that you're testing this while you're logged in so won't take effect? I tested the code and it works fine. The only other  thing I can think of is that there is another action with a higher priority doing something first which prevents your function from running.

Comment: I am testing on another browser (Logged out) the code works fine when specifying the page ID. However, I am looking for a way to say "If any page is visited by a logged out user, redirect to login custom URL"

Comment: Try this way:

if ( ! is_page( array( 123, 'login-page', 'contact-us') ) && .....

    123 would be the home page id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just eliminate the page check?  Untested.

```
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
```

Comment: I have tried without the page check and also tried is_page() as mentioned in wordpress docs

Comment: I had a cache plugin active. Upon disabling the plugin it works.